# Explicit inline annotation with AngularJs Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am used to injecting dependencies with inline annotations like this

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('SampleController',['$scope','ngDependacy',sampleController]);

function sampleController($scope,ngDependacy) {
    //do something
}
```

However right now am trying to inject another dependency with an object as the name, and am getting errors. Below is what I have

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('SampleController',['$scope','ng.Dependacy',sampleController]);

function sampleController($scope,ng.Dependacy) {
    //do something
}
```

How can I be able to inject this dependency with a dot as part of the name

Answer (score 0):

You can try following annotation:

```
var MyController = function($scope, ngDependecy) {
  // ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ng.Dependecy'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

Check: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

`$inject` Property Annotation

However remember that such construction :

```
function sampleController($scope,ng.Dependecy) {
  //do something
}
```

Won't work in JavaScript swap `ng.Dependency` with some other name like `ngDependency` in function's parameters.

Example in jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Oski/zjFp4/1313/